# How to use join on TableAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, dataset

So I have a DataSet file with some TableAdapters where main query is just a select  from all main columns

problem is that I want to make a join so i can get the string value from the parent table but i get incorrect input string format exception when i do this....

this is the adapters

```
|   Inventory    |       |   Employee      |
|      ID int    |       |      ID int     | 
|   employee int | ----- |   Name nvarchar |
|  warehouse int |
```

I tried to do this in a stored procedure and make the join clause

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spx_SELECT_InventariosByCustomPaging') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spx_SELECT_InventariosByCustomPaging
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spx_SELECT_InventariosByCustomPaging
        @startIndex     int,
    @pageSize       int     

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

  SELECT ID, Name, Warehouse, DataCriacao
  FROM (
         SELECT InventarioID, xc.Name, xa.Warehouse, DataCriacao, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(ORDER BY Colaborador DESC) AS rowNumber 
         FROM Inventory xi
         LEFT JOIN Employee xc
         ON xc.ID= xi.ID
                 LEFT JOIN xArmazem xa
                 ON xa.ArmazemID = xi.Armazem
  ) AS Inventario
  WHERE rowNumber > @startIndex AND
  rowNumber <= (@startIndex + @pageSize )

END
```

How can I get the Name column on Inventory DataTable?

> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in Inventory Column.  Expected type is Int.

Comment: Does the stored procedure work when you execute it in SSMS?   This sounds like a C# error, not a SQL error, but you don't show any of your C# code, so impossible to tell.

Comment: yes it does work on sql

Comment: Then show us the C# code, since that's where the problem is.

Comment: You are connection an employee int with a Name nvarchar.  You can't associate an integer with a string.

Comment: Thing is i just want to display the column data and keep storing it as int, hence why im using join but i don-t understand why it doesn-t detect this or if is there a different way to do this in DataSet file